# While retrieving events in web3 js, i am getting "invalid address" error

Tags: go-ethereum, solidity, web3js

Using the following code, i am trying to retrieve events:

```
var invoiceAbi = invoiceContractAbi;

var invoiceAddress = invoiceContractAddressAddress;

var invoiceInterface = web3.eth.contract(invoiceAbi).at(invoiceAddress);

var invoiceEvent = invoiceInterface.invoiceFinanced({}, { fromBlock: 15971, toBlock: 'latest' });


var i = 0;

invoiceEvent.watch(function (error, result) {
console.log(i++ + ": " + JSON.stringify(result));
});
```

I ve used actual abi and contract address. Once i run the following command, i get an error:

```
var invoiceEvent = invoiceInterface.invoiceFinanced({}, { fromBlock: 15971, toBlock: 'latest' });
```

Error:

```
invalid address
at web3.js:3887:15
at web3.js:3713:20
at web3.js:4939:28
at web3.js:4938:12
at web3.js:4964:18
at web3.js:4989:23
at web3.js:4055:16
at web3.js:4141:16
at <anonymous>:1:20
```

What should i do?

Comment: What is invoiceContractAddressAddress? What it contains?

Comment: It is a good practice that accepting the answer as correct if it helped you resolved the issue. That is the whole point of SE [none of the answers for your questions](http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/users/4964/rahul-sharma) are marked as correct. FYI, if youre not aware of it.